# What happened to Obi-Wan's lightsaber after his encounter with Darth Vader?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, a-new-hope

In *A New Hope*, when Darth Vader and Obi Wan engaged in a fight, Obi Wan was killed. At that time, his lightsaber fell there and Luke didn't retrieve it.

So, what happened to it? Was it destroyed?

Comment: [Identical Q over at Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127363/what-happened-to-obi-wans-lightsaber-after-the-duel-between-obi-wan-and-darth-v)

Comment: It rolled into a corner behind some packing crates where it was found by a maintenance worker who tried to auction it on Ebay, but there was a lawsuit by the Jedi High Command, acting as Obi-Wan's de facto executor, which prevented the sale from going through. In the end I think it ended up in a drawer in a file cabinet in some lawyers office somewhere, where it will probably sit until proton decay sets in.

Comment: I think it will get a standalone movie like "Rogue One" to explain this issue. "The last saber" where they follow the different characters that possesed the saber after Obi One died. (Would be cool ;))

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the movie canon we don't really know the fate of Obi Wan's lightsaber yet. And this is even his [third lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi's_third_lightsaber).

But in old expanded canon [Junior Jedi Knights](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Junior_Jedi_Knights), Vader keep Obi-Wan's third saber as a trophy. And also reached in the hand of [Anakin Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Solo) later.

But remember it's not even canon now and Anakin Solo might not even exist in new continuity.

> In April 2014, Lucasfilm announced that all previously released expanded universe content would be declared non-canon and rebranded as Star Wars Legends. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_expanded_universe)

So the old canon answers don't apply anymore and new canon didn't give the answer yet.

Comment: Also in the Legends Canon, it eventually found it's way to Anakin Solo, Han's second son.

Answer (score 14):

In **movie canon**, the last time we see it is after the dramatic conclusion of the duel between Darth Vader and Obi-Wan Kenobi. As Darth Vader strikes his final blow, Obi-Wan turns into a Force ghost, leaving his clothes and weapon behind. We see the lightsaber last among his robes, as an unbelieving Darth Vader examines it by kicking it with his foot.

We don't see it afterwards, unlike Luke's first / Anakin's old lightsaber that seemed lost on Bespin but turns up at Maz Kanata's.

We may *speculate* that Darth Vader picked it up, but there's no evidence that it survived the destruction of the Death Star.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that Vader took it and left it inside some safe or in his quarters.I do not believe he had it with him when he boarded his tie fighter, prior to the Death Star being blown to bits.

If the light-saber was not destroyed by the explosion and is still out there, it is floating in space somewhere in the outer rim by now.